# all day appointment for ics calendar file wont work

Tags: php, icalendar

I am trying to create events from my ical file. The events are "all day", but I can't seem to get it working correctly.

The validator says it can't parse the date:

http://severinghaus.org/projects/icv/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gamingonlinux.com%2Fcalendar_ical.php

Here's how I'm showing the date:

```
DTSTART:VALUE=DATE:20150102  
DTEND:VALUE=DATE:20150103
```

The whole file is here: https://www.gamingonlinux.com/calendar_ical.php

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it, had my ; and : mixed up.

Needed to be:
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20150102
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20150103